# How to avoid "empty string exception" with EditText

Tags: android

I've got simple application consisting of 2 screens.

On the first I've got EditText view and button.

When user entry text and press button, main screen changes and user can see typed value together with switch button that's there for returning to previous destination.

The problem's when  user haven't typed anything and press button. I've got exception that says, "string is empty".

I've tried using textChangedListener but that isn't working.
First screen consist of ViewModel and MutableLiveData object for storing typed value.

Here's the code:

Main screen:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private MainViewModel mViewModel;

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);


    // TODO: Use the ViewModel


    EditText editText = getView().findViewById(R.id.valueEntry);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            mViewModel.setValue(Float.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()));
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            return;
        }
    });

    Button button = getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        MainFragmentDirections.MoveToSecond action = MainFragmentDirections.moveToSecond( );
        action.setVal(mViewModel.getValue());
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
        }
    });

}
```

ViewModel instance:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {



    private MutableLiveData<Float> value  = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void setValue(Float c){value.setValue(c);}
    public Float getValue()
    {
            return  value.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code when the user pressed the button

```
if (!entered_sting.equals(""))
{
   // show text to other works
}
```

use this if in first of button press event

Comment: That's works without need to implements TextWatcher.

Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome. It was so easy. I am a 14 years old programmer. If you like, you can follow my Twitter, I will tweet about programming there. My DMs are open there.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner option would be to check for an empty string and not for `equals("")`

```
if (!entered_sting.trim().isEmpty())
{
   // show text to other works
}
```